# WSO2 api manager 2.1.0 clustering

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to setup WSO2 api manager(as windows service) with clustering, used steps at the end of the page found at this link.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
            enable="true">
```

I have 2 nodes in a load balancer, I have all 4 components(Publisher
,Store,Key Manager,Gateway) on both nodes. When setup individually, both nodes work.

However, when clustering is enabled, store does not replicate from one node to another. I have hosts file updated as needed. I tried making several changes to axis2.xml, api-manager.xml; some of these changes cause api manager to stop working altogether.

Does anyone have suggestions for a successful clustering setup? Is there something that is needed, is not mentioned in the steps mentioned at above link?

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation that you are following is not the relevant one. If you are clustering WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 version please use [API Manager 2.1.0 clustering docuemntation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Clustering+the+API+Manager) which is inside the API Manager product documentation itself.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried instructions from documention at this link. I still have the same issue that node2 will stop working completely (unable to reach store/publisher) with some of these changes or store is not replicated from one node to the other.

Comment: What is the load balacing Software that you are using ?